# How do I get the $index of element in an ng-repeat when repeating over an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know object values don't have indexes but say I have an object named foo with 5 keys and I do:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in foo">
```

I will end up with 5 divs on my page.

My question is how do I ask Angular, "Hey, which div is this? Is it the first one? Is it the second one? Give me a number please." I can't use `{{$index}}` because objects don't have indexes. I can't use `{{$id}}` because it seems to give a number that starts from 5 and is always odd... sometimes. I just want to know where in the `ng-repeat` I am when repeating over an object and not an array.

Comment: If all you want is display numbering use an `<ol>` and browser will do the numbering. Otherwise what is your use case for needing the indexing?

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: @BonMacalindong why would that help? What more is needed to know than it is an object?

Comment: Using `$index` seems to work just fine for me, even as far back as Angular version 1.2.1. [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ebad1g49/).

Comment: Did you just assume that `$index` wouldn't work for an object, or did you test it and find it actually didn't work? [Here is the place in the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L333) where `$index` is defined on the scope regardless of whether the collection being repeated is an array or object.

Comment: I'm asking because $index seems to work for me too. I created a fiddle just to simulate. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4301s9v/)

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  What are you trying to do that you need to know which div is which?  If you are modelling your data correctly, you should be able to work with your data elements, regardless of their position in your UI.

Comment: @GregL I'm only here because, yes, I did try it every way I could imagine. Using '$index' didn't and still does not work for me. I honestly don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @GregL I've even tried making the simplest possible angular app I could just to get rid of all other variables and $index works every time on arrays and none of the time on objects. Do you have any more information about it?

Comment: @EricHannum What version of AngularJS? Have you checked in the ngRepeat code for the Angular JS file you are using to see if there is logic to omit setting the `$index` property on the item scope when repeating over objects?

Comment: @EricHannum Did you try out [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4301s9v/) and did it work for you? You should be able to see that even as far back as AngularJS version 1.2.1, `$index` worked for objects just fine. Do you have something modifying the behaviour of `ngRepeat`, perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could still use `{{$index}}` when repeating non array objects.

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
      <span>{{$index}} -</span>
      <span>{{key}} -</span>
      <span>{{value}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function testCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b',
    prop3: 'c',
    prop4: 'c'
  }

}
```

**Output:**

```
0 - prop1 - a
1 - prop2 - b
2 - prop3 - c
3 - prop4 - c
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4301s9v/) for your reference

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there just isn't a way to get your position in an ng-repeat loop other than $index and that only works for arrays. So one possible solution is to just unzip you object into an array before using it. If angular wants an array, give it one.

Comment: From my testing and looking at the source (see my comments above), it appears that you are incorrect in saying that `$index` can only be used for arrays.

Comment: It doesn't work for me nor has it ever. I ran into this same problem recently which is why I'm here. I have never seen $index work when used with an object. Only arrays.