# passing object from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<td ng-repeat="data in data_legend" rowspan="2"></td>
```

Here , the data_legend is a **dynamic array** filled by *user* from the **Form**.Now the idea is to display all the dynamic content to the user and i need to know which element in the array is edited ?

Any Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you trying to set the ngmodel to the index?

Comment: data_legend contains all the data collected from user and ng-repeat show all of them . Now, my idea is to bind those data to ng-model in order to recognize which one is edited. @BryanEuton

Comment: None of this makes sense. Why would you need `ng-model` on a `<td>`? Also `ng-model` should always be an object ... using a number makes no sense

Comment: which one is edited is already known by the object `data`. This is all an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Need a far better explanation of exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: hey @charlietfl, may be i am wrong . but please can you tell me how do i dynamically bind the input received from user ?

Comment: Charlietfl is correct.  In the td, you can pass data to the change function in your controller.  If you have a question on how to do that, update your html in the question.

Comment: what i am trying to do here is to show the user data_legend in a loop and if they are interested in editing it . i need to know which one is edited ?

Comment: Simply pass the whole object to any controller functions you need to use to do editing. `ng-repeat` has already isolated it for you

Comment: @charlietfl thanks . i was quiet confused with the ng thing i didn't though of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass current data in iteration to a function .

**Example :**

```
//Here I'm passing the current data object in array and its index to editData().

//$index will provide you the location of this data in array

<table ng-repeat="data in data_legend">
  <tr rowspan="2" ng-click="editData(data, $index)">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.price}}</td> 
    <td>{{data.year}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$scope.editData = function(data,index){

//Do something to data 

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: $index can be used without "track by" proof : http://codepen.io/lsgrrd/pen/pnvwf?editors=1010

Comment: this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934670/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-element-in-an-ng-repeat-when-repeating-over-an-object